Notifications are shown only as a popup in Windows, but not anywhere else
I'm using Google Chat API to send messages to one space, which are marked as private. They are received, but the space is not listed in bolt font in the list of spaces nor is notification on mobile received. It's only shown as a popup in Windows, not anywhere else. I have set the space to receive all notifications.Message in space Windows popup notification
I use the official google api python package. I build the chat api using service account token, then send a message like this. The sender is a google (app) chat bot, which is listed only for our company.
chat = build("chat", "v1", credentials=credentials)
body = {
    "text": notification_text,
    "privateMessageViewer": {
        "name": f"users/{user.get('email')}",
    },
}
message = (
    chat.spaces()
    .messages()
    .create(parent=f"spaces/{space_id}", body=body)
    .execute()
)


And what is your actual question? [ask]
